# ssl error record too long using UI CloudStack

Tags: apache, ssl, cloud

I have just finished automatic installation of CloudStack.

Now I want to connect to the user interface with Firefox on a remote host.

So I enter `https://192.168.xxx.xxx:8080/client`

and I get the error `ssl_error_rx_record_too_long`

How can I solve this? I can only use `cli` to interact with the CloudStack Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a weird symptom of using HTTPS over a port listening on HTTP. Change your protocol to HTTP or find out your actual HTTPS port.

Comment: To add more detail: Since you are not talking to a HTTPS server but to a HTTP server the server will respond with some error to the invalid HTTP request (invalid because it is the start of a TLS handshake). The client then will try to interpret the HTTP error as a TLS response  which can result in a myriad of errors, like bad record, handshake failure, bad protocol... and also record too long.